# JavaScript Quote Generator with Options

Tags: javascript

I`m working on a project and I have to build a quote generator with JavaScript.
The requirements for the project are below:

- Select the number of quotes generated (between 1 and 5)
- Choose between 2 types of quote generators (accordingly, you'll need two different sets of sentences)
- Once the quotes are generated, have the program generate new quotes or quit the program

I did 2 generators which are generating random sentences from 3 and 4 fragments. Those 2 generators are working from 2 different buttons

Select the number of quotes generated (between 1 and 5)- Trying to do that with 2 prompts and loop but not really working for the moment. The prompt appears but once the user types in the desired amount of quotes nothing happens.

Once the quotes are generated, have the program generate new quotes or quit the program - Thinking  of using another prompt

My js code:

```js
var beg = [`Peter `, `Michael`, `Lorna`, `Diana`, `Maria`]
var mid = [`prefer`, `looks after`, `has`, `works with`, `is breeding`]
var end = [`dobermans`, `labradors`, `grate danes`, `french buldogs`, `rotweilers`]
function generateQuote() {
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (beg.length));
  var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (mid.length));
  var randomNumber4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (end.length));
  for (let i = 0; i < beg.length + mid.length + end.length; i++)
    var randomQuote = beg[randomNumber1] + ` ` + mid[randomNumber2] + ` ` + ` ` + end[randomNumber4]
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = [randomQuote];
}
var begg = [`She `, `He`, `It`, `Maddie`, `Josh`]
var midd = [`likes`, `hates`, `loves`, `dislikes`, `adores`]
var midd1 = [`well- trained`, `nice`, `adorable`, `fluffy`, `goodlooking`]
var endd = [`animals`, `pets`, `dogs`, `cats`, `spiders`]
function generateQuote1() {
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (begg.length));
  var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (midd.length));
  var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (midd1.length));
  var randomNumber4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (endd.length));
  var randomQuote = begg[randomNumber1] + ` ` + midd[randomNumber2] + ` ` + midd1[randomNumber3] + ` ` + endd[randomNumber4]
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = [randomQuote];
}
var quoteNumber = prompt("How many quotes you would like to generate?", "1");
if (quotenumber != null) {}
```

```html
<h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
<div id="quoteDisplay">
  <!-- Quotes will display here -->
</div>
<button onclick="generateQuote() ">First type Quote</button>

<button onclick="generateQuote1() ">Second type Quote</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = [randomQuote]`. randomQuote is a string not an array here so you could do `document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = randomQuote`.

Also consider using a for loop here if you want to generate multiple quotes. E.g. `for(i =0; i < 5; i++)` do `quotesArray.push(randomQuote)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you supposed to have one button on HTML that will generate the quote with the function from the script:

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="getQuote()">Get New Quote</button>
```

and in your script.js you should use a different variable to generate the random function and add it to your HTMLPage **OR** console:

````
document.getElementById('').innerHTML = //add your fragments together here```
````

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide more detail with your answer and if possible, a code suggestion to fix the issue (with a jsfiddle would be best).

Answer (score 0):

Use ES6 Template Literals to display your code on the webpage document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = `"${beg[randomNumber1]} ${mid[randomNumber2]} ${end[randomNumber3]}"`;

and you can also check it on console: console.log(`"${beg[randomNumber1]} ${mid[randomNumber2]} ${end[randomNumber3]}"`)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for your response. I removed the brackets and tried your solution but not sure if I get it right

Here is what I did:

```
function generateQuote() {
    var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() *  (beg.length));
    var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() *  (mid.length));
    var randomNumber4 = Math.floor(Math.random() *  (end.length));
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        quotesArray.push(randomQuote)
    }
```